# Printing an html page with TCPDF in laravel 4

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, laravel-4

So I have an html document which I am writing inside a long string called $content. I am supposed to pass this string to a pdf builder object to print it as a pdf file.

Only problem is the pdf file has a line at the bottom that interferes with my cotent when it reaches the bottom of the page like this table 
[image]

As you can see the pdf footer line crosses my table and I don't want this to happen. I want to somehow predict if this line is going to cross and then print the whole crossed content in another pdf page.

Comment: there's a tcpf setting, you can change to remove that, but you will have to look it up, as i cant remember what one off hand

Comment: Ramy did you happen to figure this out? It'd be very helpful!